# How to scan/search for active SQL Server instances with Java?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

Is there an easy way, using Java, to scan/search the local network for SQL Server database instances?

Comment: im thinking of doing an ACK scan and then from the machine list, check port 1433 on each machine in the list.   can anyone think of a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can get source code from the free [SQLPing](http://www.sqlsecurity.com/Tools/FreeTools/tabid/65/Default.aspx) tool to port into Java if you want.

This uses several techniques for SQL Server discovery because there is no foolproof method.
Examples:

- what port is the instance on and SQL Browser is turned off?
- is the server configued with shared memory only
- SQL Services not running

Comment: I want to scan for ONLY the tcp/1433 port.  I dont care about any of the other methods and so SQLPing is overkill.